# Key in table becomes Guid.Empty entityframework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities:

```
public class ElectedRepresentativeData : TimeTrackBase
{
    [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }

        public int RegionId { get; set; }

        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public virtual Accountants Accountants { get; set; }
}

public class Accountants : TimeTrackBase
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ElectedRepresentativeDataId { get; set; }
        public virtual Accountant Accountant { get; set; }
        public virtual AccountantSubstitute AccountantSubstitute { get; set; }
}
    public class Accountant : TimeTrackBase
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid AccountantsId { get; set; }
        public virtual Person AccountantPerson { get; set; }
    }

   public class AccountantSubstitute : TimeTrackBase
   {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid AccountantsId { get; set; }
        public virtual Person AccountantPerson { get; set; }
   }
```

The problem I have is that the AccountantsId becomes Guid.Empty(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) in the table AccountantSubstitute, while the AccountantsId in the table Accountant works as expected.

Should it not work in the AccountantSubstitute as well?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are aware that a Guid is not an identity in SQL? Identity refers to the SQL Server "Identity" feature, which IMHO is not applicable for GUID's.

Comment: AccountantsId is even configured to be a Foreign Key Property?

Answer (score 0):

You must create a configuration class and configure properties in more detail.

```cs
   public class AccountantConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Accountant>
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Communication> builder)
        {
            if (builder == null)
                return;

            builder.ToTable("Accountant");

            builder.HasKey(k => new {Id = k.Id});

            builder.Property(p => p.Id)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.AccountantsId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValueSql("newid()")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            ...

        }
    }
```

And add this configuration in DbContext class

```cs
public sealed class Context : DbContext
{

    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        if (builder == null) 
            return;

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new AccountantConfiguration());
    }
}
```